# Python Traceback (most recent call last): TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

My code does have output like this:

```
0.0
17424.9931038
0.999998852224
0.0
26892.5610797
0.9999992563
0.0
197429.598938
0.999999898698
0.0
206067.715126
0.999999902945
0.0
119901.778166
0.999999833197
0.0
48243.1852781
0.999999585434
0.0
161251.135425
0.99999987597
0.0
460059.512284
0.999999956527
0.0
1616904.64834
0.999999987631
20.0
10048.6928044
0.999998009693
20.0
19783.0112229
0.999998989032
20.0
106444.618031
0.999999812109
20.0
208645.708656
0.999999904144
20.0
85754.2720566
0.999999766775
20.0
35024.1659145
0.999999428966
20.0
162536.879087
0.999999876951
20.0
494504.420369
0.999999959555
20.0
1523905.77844
0.999999986876
40.0
7539.80921955
0.999997347417
40.0
20041.735046
0.999999002083
40.0
58683.4742137
0.999999659189
40.0
234270.969023
0.999999914629
40.0
49306.4157177
0.999999594373
40.0
27876.4404592
0.999999282549
40.0
165300.231338
0.999999879008
40.0
568614.839048
0.999999964827
40.0
1502387.8595
0.999999986688
60.0
4544.45338191
0.99999559904
60.0
21050.154867
0.999999049889
60.0
29282.4962414
0.999999316998
60.0
261564.996448
0.999999923537
60.0
24097.4648119
0.999999170038
...
```

But then it errors with traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2_moving.py", line 34, in <module>
    print moving(my_data)
  File "2_moving.py", line 29, in moving
    print dist2(k,l)
  File "2_moving.py", line 16, in dist2
    d2 = math.hypot(m1[0]-m3[0],m1[1]-m3[1])
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My code is

```
import numpy as np
import math

my_data = np.loadtxt(open("demo_tindex.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=0)
# print my_data

def nexus(m,n):
    for k in n:
        if k[3] == m[3] and k[2] == m[2]+20:
            return k


def dist2(m1,m2):
    m3 = nexus(m2,my_data)
    d1 = math.hypot(m1[0]-m2[0],m1[1]-m2[1])
    d2 = math.hypot(m1[0]-m3[0],m1[1]-m3[1])
    d3 = math.hypot(m2[0]-m3[0],m2[1]-m3[1])
    dist2 = (d1+d2)**2 - d3**2
    return dist2


def moving(p):
    k = p[0][:]
    theta2 = 0.02

    for l in p[1:]:
        if l[2] == k[2]:
            print l[2]
            print dist2(k,l)
            print math.exp(-theta2/dist2(k,l))
        else:
            k = l

print moving(my_data)
```

this file is csv file in the code
[demo_tindex.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-h9m0fKavGUcUlyXzVTOUlrbFU/view?usp=sharing)

And this question is to calculate the influence map from dataset
[image: image here]

Comment: `m1` or `m3` is `None` in the indicated line.

Comment: @deceze. Definitely not `m1` if the previous line ran.

Comment: @DaliVan. I am going to go ahead and answer your question because there are some concepts here that I believe are really non-intuitive to a Python beginner, and I am in a very good mood this morning. You have received a number of downvotes because you have shown no real effort to solve this on your own, despite clearly having access to a computer with a working internet connection, and Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you interpret this error:

In Python, every operator redirects to some special function on the class of your object. In this case, the operator `[...]` is equivalent to calling `__getitem__`. It is the same operator for both sequences and dictionaries.

The issue is with `m3`. You can know this immediately because the previous line does not raise an error for `m1` and `m2`. `m3` comes for searching for some attributes of `m2` in `my_data` using the `nexus` function*.

This would normally be OK, but in some cases a match is not found. The default return value of *every* Python function that does not have an explicit return statement is `None`, which is what `nexus` inevitably returns when a match is not found.

The easiest fix for this would be to return a sequence from `nexus` even if a match is not found. For example, add `return [0, 0]` as the last line of your function. Alternatively, you can add a check for a `None` result in `dist2`, but then you have to figure out what to return and how to handle it in `moving`.

---

*I should probably mention at some point that I have no idea what your code is really doing, but that should not affect the accuracy of my answer.

Comment: The data  `[x1,y1,t1,p1]` means the x-axis, y-axis, time frame and person number. I use `m3` to get the array of the person appeared in the next frame. So I use `nexus` to get the information and calculate the distance `d2(x,MPi)`. I also searched on google and stackoverflow, but they all focus on the Nonetype. I knew there are some errors in `m1`,`m2` and `m3` unfortunately I cannot fix it. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @DaliVan. In that case, you can make the last line of `nexus` read `raise ValueError('Person %d did not appear in the following frame' % m[p])` or something like that. It will be much more informative than an error that crops up elsewhere for obscure reasons.